# How to handle n-m relationships with my PHP models?

Tags: php, database, oop, coding-style, complexity-theory

I'm writing the specification for someone to create a model generator based on an existing database. I have created the below dummy database to illustrate the specification:

[image]

And here is a code snippet showing how the various tables should be manipulated:

```
<?php
// DISPLAYING VALUES
$companies = new $Companies();
$companies->get_all();
foreach ($companies as $company) {
    echo "Company name: " . $company->name;
    // 1-n relationship FROM company table so company_type is 1 object
    echo "Type of company: " . $company->company_type->name;
    // 1-n relationship TO company table so portfolios is a collection of 0
    // or more objects
    foreach ($company->portfolios as $portfolio) {
        foreach ($portfolio->customers as $customer) {
            echo $customer->amount_of_contract;
            echo $customer->name;
        }
    }
}

// ADDING A PORTFOLIO
$companies = new $Companies;
$company = $companies->get_by_name('mycompany');
$portfolio = new $Portofolio;
$portfolio->company_id = $company->id;
$portfolio->year = '2012';
$portfolio->create();
```

As I'm not very technical I don't really know whether the above is possible, and if so what the amount of work entailed with generating the corresponding models is. Accordingly I would like to ask the following questions:

**Q1: From a coding style, do you see anything that would not be (reasonably) implementable?**

**Q2: Would it add any value to have an extra step for the `portfolio_has_customer` table or is accessing the `amount_of_contract` property via the `customer` object like above OK?**

**Q3: Is there an alternative for handling the `n-m` relationship of `portfolio_has_customer` that would be less complex to implement than the one described above?**

Comment: Class names do not begin with $ (unless you have variables called `$Companies` and `$Portofolio`).

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:** Syntax resembles ORM used by [kohana framework](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/), for me it looks implementable

**Q2:** Such use of pivot table can be encountered sometimes, the only thing that looks weird to me is the way you access the property (I've seen more often additional relationship between portfolio and portfolio_has_customer), although don't take it for granted

**Q3:** no, I'm not aware of anything less complex

Comment: you know you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10669230/edit) your answer rather than leaving comments to add more information?